# Why is this code not outputting expected result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

I have the following jQuery that builds nested DOM elements and appends it into the current DOM. But in the result the elements aren't quite nested properly and the output is a bit off visually.

```js
const urlHash = "example";
       $("#myBookmarks").append(
    $('<div/>', {'class': 'bookmark list-group-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix','draggable': 'true'}).append(
     $('<div/>', {'class': ''}).append(
      $('<div/>', {'class': 'col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-7', 'id': urlHash}).append(
     $('<a/>', {'href': linkURL, 'id': urlHash, 'draggable': 'false'}).append(
      t))).append(
     $('<div/>', {'class': 'text-right col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-5'}).append(
      $('<a/>', {'class': 'btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit'})).append(
      $('<button/>', {'class': 'btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete'}))
     )
    )
   )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myBookmarks"></div>
```

Expected results:

```
<div class="bookmark list-group-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix" draggable="true">
    <div class="">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-7">
            <a href="https://amazon.com" id="-7946160306639565623" draggable="false">Amazon</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-5">
            <a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit" role="button" title="Edit Bookmark" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
            <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete" title="Delete Bookmark"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Actual results where the dom elements aren't quite nested correctly and such:

```
<div class="">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-7" id="[object HTMLInputElement]"><a href="https://amazon.com" id="55555"
            draggable="false">Amazon</a></div>
    <div class="text-right col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-5"><a
            class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit"></a><button
            class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete"></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You seem to forgot to tell us what the issue is.

Comment: I haven't got out a microscope, but your code *seems* to create that structure or something very much like it...?

Comment: I do not see any problems here. Except the minor details like you gave ID 'example' to a div in your code but is not there in your example of expected code. or instead of class='' it just shows class.

Comment: I added the actual output. The nesting is a little off, but I have looked it over for over an hour to see if something is off, and the code appears to be to be correct to me.

Comment: Trying to read that code makes my brain hurt!

Comment: FWIW, in the modern world you can just use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this: https://pastebin.com/pYfPjGuL. You can transpile for obsolete browsers, using tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io).

Comment: Yes, append does not add the whitespace.... So sf that is what you are complaining about?

Comment: One problem I noticed is that the first div gets closed immediately. I tried to show it in the 'Actual output' section but I the stupid editor isn't showing it. Idk. 

I do like what @T.J.Crowder said. I'll give that a go. I didn't know it was quite that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way rather than a long append chain.

```
const urlHash = "example";
const linkURL = "https://amazon.com";

var emptyCLassDiv = appendAndGetElement($("#myBookmarks"), 'div', {
    'class': 'bookmark list-group-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix',
    'draggable': 'true'});

var firstDivChild = appendAndGetElement(emptyCLassDiv, 'div', {
    'class': 'col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-7',
    'id': urlHash
});

appendAndGetElement(firstDivChild, 'a', {
   'href': linkURL,'id': urlHash,'text': 'Amazon','draggable': 'false'
});

var secondDivChild = appendAndGetElement(emptyCLassDiv, 'div', {
   'class': 'text-right col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-5'
});

appendAndGetElement(secondDivChild, 'a', {
  'class': 'btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit',
  'role': 'button',
  'title': 'Edit Bookmark',
  'href': '#',
  'draggable': 'false'
});

appendAndGetElement(secondDivChild, 'button', {
   'class': 'btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete',
   'title': 'Delete Bookmark'
});

function appendAndGetElement($parentEle, eleType, attr) {
   var newEle = $('<' + eleType + '/>', attr);
  $parentEle.append(newEle);
  return newEle;
}
```

But if you absolutely need the original long append chain solution. 
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/602q1ock/) that creates the required HTML.